# PHPUnit mock objects and method type hinting

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to create a mock object of \SplObserver using PHPunit and attach the mocked object to an \SplSubject.  When I try to attach the mocked object to a class that implements \SplSubject, I get a catchable fatal error saying that the mocked object doesn't implement \SplObserver:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to ..\AbstractSubject::attach() must implement interface SplObserver, instance of PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker given, called in ../Decorator/ResultCacheTest.php on line 44 and defined in /users/.../AbstractSubject.php on line 49
```

More or less, here's the code:

```
// Edit: Using the fully qualified name doesn't work either
$observer = $this->getMock('SplObserver', array('update'))
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('update');

// Attach the mock object to the cache object and listen for the results to be set on cache
$this->_cache->attach($observer);

doSomethingThatSetsCache();
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using PHP 5.3 and PHPUnit 3.4.9

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### Update

Oh, actually, the problem is pretty simple, but somehow hard to spot. Instead of:

```
$observer = $this->getMock('SplObserver', array('update'))
                 ->expects($this->once())
                 ->method('update');
```

You have to write:

```
$observer = $this->getMock('SplObserver', array('update'));
$observer->expects($this->once())
         ->method('update');
```

That's because `getMock()` returns a different thing than `method()`, that's why you got the error. You passed the wrong object to `attach`.

#### Original answer

I think you have to fully qualify the type of the mock:

```
$observer = $this->getMock('\SplObserver', array('update'));
```

Comment: Yes!  That was it -- I was trying to get too clever with the fluent interface.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to be clear, the class indeed must be fully qualified *in addition to* calling expects() separately.